# Can't install caret package in R

Tags: r, rstudio, r-caret

I have tried multiple ways to install the `caret` package in R.
The error message that I receive is as follows:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    there is no package called ‘dimRed’

When I try to install `dimRed`, I get the following message:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Thomas/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘Biobase’ is not available

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
   binary source needs_compilation
dimRed  0.1.0  0.2.1             FALSE

installing the source package ‘dimRed’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dimRed_0.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 363025 bytes (354 KB)
downloaded 354 KB
```

> ERROR: dependency 'Biobase' is not available for package 'dimRed'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/Thomas/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/dimRed'
>   In R CMD INSTALL
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqKhsKn/downloaded_packages/dimRed_0.2.1.tar.gz' had status 1
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘dimRed’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>       ‘C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqKhsKn\downloaded_packages’

Per previous posts, I have updated RStudio.  I have attempted an install from install_url.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried installing `biobase` first? See the [documentation](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biobase.html) for installation help

Comment: These are confusing messages. Biobase is a Bioconductor package. Neither it, nor dimRed seem to be required for caret, according to [its CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html). It sounds like your current R environment is just messed up. I would restart R and try again.

Comment: It's possible that one of the package required by `caret`(and there are a big boatload of them) does have `dimRed` as a dependency. I just installed `caret` and dimRed was installed during the dependencies phase. Si suggestions to reinstall my be a waste of time. (I did already have Biobase installed.)

Comment: I ran install.packages("dimRed", dependencies = T) and now my base error message has changed to - > library("caret")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘Biobase’.  When I try to install Biobase, I'm told that it is not available on R3.4.4.  Any ideas?

Comment: I had a similar problem. In my case, as @neilfws mentioned, some of the libraries were likely open in my on-going RStudio session. I just re-started RStudio, used `install.packages("caret", dependencies = TRUE)` and all was fine.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to figure this out.
Simply typing install.packages won't work. In order to install Biobase, you have to run the following code in R console:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("Biobase", version = "3.8")
```

More info: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biobase.html

Once this step is done, I installed caret again using

```
install.packages("caret",dependencies = T)
```

And then it worked.

Comment: I have had the same issue as the questioner. I attempted this and once I tried `library(caret)` I got the same 1st error as the questioner.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the R version, as pointed out by a previous response. I was using R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) under Windows 10 Pro. And I used install.packages("caret",dependencies = T). You can try this out and see if there are any dependencies other than the Biobase package for caret.

Comment: Didn't wrk for me

Answer (score -1):

Warning ...

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
```

This only works if your R version is >= 3.5.0

for info I've the same problem under a Centos and a Windows.
issue solved on the windows with 3.5.1 R version. Not yet solved on the centOS (3.4.2)